# How to prove that any Boolean function can be simulated only using AND gate and NOT gate?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to see how to prove the functional completeness of NAND gate, but all the materials in the web I have reached just relies on the fact that the set $\{AND,NOT\}$ is complete and shows how to simulate those gates only using NAND gate. I want to see the proof or some list of references which contains the proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what more you want. The proof that $\{\land, \lnot\}$ is complete?

Comment: @Tunococ I think so.

Comment: (i) Maybe you need to show that  $\lnot$, $\land$, and $\lor$ together form a complete set. Or maybe that has already been done. (ii)  Show that $\lor$ can be done with $\lnot$ and $\land$.

Comment: @Tunococ Yes, exactly

Comment: @André Nicolas   I have done (ii) but have no idea as to (i).

Comment: prove it by induction on the number of variables. $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = (x_n \land f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,1)) \lor (\lnot  x_n \land f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,0))$

Comment: Look at a "truth table"  for our function $f$. If always $0$, easy. If not always $0$, look at all values of $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for which the function is $1$. For each such $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, form the conjunction $A_j$ of $\lnot x_i$ where $a_i=0$ and $x_i$  if $a_i=1$. Then form the disjunction of all the $A_j$. We have obtained the important **disjunctive normal form** (DNF).

Answer (score 3):

As confirmed by the OP, I'll simply write down the proof that $\{\land, \lnot\}$ is complete.

There are four possible choices for a pair of truth values (00, 01, 10, 11). There are $2^4 = 16$ possible functions from $\{00, 01, 10, 11\}$ to $\{0, 1\}$. For simplicity, I will represent a function by a sequence of its values on $00, 01, 10, 11$ respectively. For example, $0001$ is the AND function. $0111$ is the OR function.

Here is one way to construct 8 out of 16 binary functions using only $\land$ and $\lnot$:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
0000: & (p, q) \mapsto p \land \lnot p \\
0001: & (p, q) \mapsto p \land q \\
0010: & (p, q) \mapsto p \land \lnot q \\
0011: & (p, q) \mapsto p \\
0100: & (p, q) \mapsto \lnot p \land q \\
0101: & (p, q) \mapsto q \\
0110: & (p, q) \mapsto \lnot (p \land q) \land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \\
0111: & (p, q) \mapsto \lnot (\lnot p \land \lnot q)
\end{array}
$$
Now observe that if we negate each of these functions, we obtain all the remaining 8 functions.

Comment: It seems you are implicitly assuming that only considering Boolean functions form of $f:B^2 \to B$ is enough, but I am afraid this implicit fact seems nontrivial to me..

Comment: @Guldam because this is  enough to prove the $B^n \to B$ case by induction on $n$ : $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = (x_n \land f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,1)) \lor (\lnot  x_n \land f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,0))$ where the latter are functions $B^{n-1} \to B$

Comment: @user1952009 I see. All of my problems are resolved now. Thanks everyone!